# How can you compare product category performance to previous years with Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce?

Tags: google-analytics

We upgraded to Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce a few months ago, but there doesn't seem to be a way to compare Product Category Performance to previous years (when we didn't have Enhanced Ecommerce).

While you can compare revenue, there's no category data. The new dimension is called *Product Category (Enhanced Ecommerce)* vs *Product Category* before so I can see why you probably can't compare, but it seems like a huge omission and this is how we run our business.

Is there an easy workaround to get this data without pulling all data manually and comparing offline?

Is this a feature that's being worked on?

I also posted in the product forum but got response: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/Pu6L7WAko9g.

Answer (score 1):

There would not be any enhanced e-commerce data recorded for previous years.

As indicated in the video [here](https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/course01/unit?unit=3&lesson=1) and text version [here](https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/course01/assets/pdf/DigitalAnalyticsFundamentals-Lesson3.1HowGoogleAnalyticsworksText.pdf) from Google's Analytics Academy:

> It’s important to note that once the data has been processed and
>   inserted into the database, it can’t be changed

You can go to your Product Performance Report and add a secondary dimension. You should then be able to have the first dimension Product Category (Enhanced Ecommerce) and the second Product Category, but I doubt this will give you the desired result.

For more on this, see the video or text version from Google's Analytics Academy [here](https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/course01/unit?unit=6&lesson=2).

Comment: I understand that there's no old enhanced e-commerce data and that data can't be changed. My main issue is that there seems to be no clean solution to compare pre-enhanced e-commerce (existing) data with the *equivalent* enhanced-ecommerce data. From a backend perspective, I can understand why this isn't possible out of the box, but since *everybody* is upgrading through this path, leaving old data in the dust seems like a big omission.

As for adding a secondary dimension, `Product Category` is not available once upgrading to enhanced-ecommerce.